# Linux - Как автоматически проставлять Y при установке пакетов

Tags: linux, bash, apt

В последнее время часто призодится обновлять пакеты через `apt` и `pkg`. Месяц назад где-то услышал, что можно не проставлять вручную согласие (`Y`) в каждом поле, а добавить к команде аргумент. Какой аргумент нужно добавить?

Answer (score 2):

Собственно так и писать:

```
apt-get -y install [пакет]  // apt -y install [пакет]
```

Можно быть совсем рисковым парнем и вообще игнорировать все вопросы:

```
apt-get --yes --force-yes install [пакет]  // apt --yes --force-yes install [пакет]
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Я от большинства пакетов, которые я устанавливаю/обновляю уже по несколько раз читал, с чем соглашаться, так что точно не сомневаюсь по поводу игнора вопросов :D

Comment: Ещё есть программа `yes`, которая прожимает `Y` везде. И не только его, если почитать мануал.